# You must be THIS high to ride this puzzle!

Tags: wordplay, rebus

1.[image]
2.[image]
3.[image]
4.[image]
5.[image]
6.[image]
7.[image]
8.[image]

> What is ***this***?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is none other than

> Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious

1.

> **super**script

2.

> **Calif**ornia.

3.

> **fragile** wine glass

4.

> **listic** (misspelling of lipstick)

5.

> Windows **XP**

6.

> **Alli**son from The Breakfast Club

7.

> **Doe**, a deer, a female deer.

8.

> **Shush!** The movie is playing!

Comment: Can someone help me with formatting? I can't tell why the numbers 3 and 6 are hidden?

Comment: Fixed (I think).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thank you, but now it looks like all of the numbers are hidden. How can I get all the numbers outside of the spoilers? EDIT: For me at least, the numbers are outside of the spoilers, but only show when you hover over the spoiler

Comment: As I'm seeing the post, the numbers *are* all outside of the spoilers. Are you on mobile?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I edited my comment. I'm not on mobile. I want the numbers to show when I'm not hovering over the spoilers

Comment: @Chowzen Thank you, that seems to have fixed it!

Comment: I added <br>s to it (Not on Mobile, was also not seeing numbers until hovering).

Comment: @Chowzen Do I deserve that sweet green checkbox or am I still missing something? :)

Comment: @Chowzen I've edited my answer slightly, not sure if this was needed.

Comment: No, Ur done (capitalization was not needed) I was just waiting a bit so that others might look before it's marked as 'accepted.' aka PointMilking :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75285/discussion-between-riley-and-chowzen).

Answer (score 5):

The other answer is almost certainly right, but I was convinced the answer was

> **capitalized!** The title talks about height, and all of the green *This* were all uppercase, while the black ones were in mixed case.