# What is the longest word that can be made out of all the scrabble tiles?

Tags: optimization, scrabble

What is the longest word that can be made out of all the Scrabble tiles?

If you didn’t know, there are 100 tiles when you play Scrabble. I was wondering what was the longest word you could make out of these tiles?

[Scrabble Tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions)

There is no limit on how long the words can be.
Any words that are accepted by a major dictionary count.

Extra Challenge, Make sure it could be played in scrabble, (without the fifteen letter limit) for example, oxyphenbutazone, you could play it if zone, but and ox was on the board and your rack is APHENY?

Comment: do you have wordlist for scrabble?

Comment: Is it bounded by the size of the Scrabble board?  I also don't quite remember the Scrabble rules, if there's a bound on how many tiles you can have available to play at any one time - but if so, do you require that the word has to be able to be constructed turn by turn going through valid intermediate words?

Comment: What counts as a "word" exactly? You'll need to be more specific, o r this will likely be closed as too broad.

Comment: Maybe post the extra challenge as a separate question? It has its own set of rules (like having to use Scrabble-valid words only) that are not really related to the main question.

Answer (score 6):

Since Scrabble tile counts follow the letter frequencies of English, there aren't going to be very many words that are excluded by the tile selection.

Starting with the longest words in English (according to a word list called "[british-english-insane](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/british-english-insane.5.html)" because of the number of words it includes), checking each word against [online dictionaries](http://onelook.com), and then counting how many times each letter is used in each word (with `fold -1 |sort |uniq -c |sort`), we find out that

> `Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch` has too many G's
>  `pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis` has too many C's

But then we find the winner:

> [`supercalifragilisticexpialidocious`](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/supercalifragilisticexpialidocious) has 34 letters, and needs one blank tile for the third "C".

Runners-up:

> [`dichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane`](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=dichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane), 31 letters, both blank tiles needed for the four H's
>  [`methylenedioxymethamphetamine`](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/methylenedioxymethamphetamine), 29 letters, no blank tiles needed
>  [`trinitrophenylmethylnitramine`](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trinitrophenylmethylnitramine), 29 letters, no blank tiles needed
>  [`floccinaucinihilipilification`](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/floccinaucinihilipilification), 29 letters, both blank tiles needed for the four C's

Comment: I thought it was [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62967/you-must-be-this-high-to-ride-this-puzzle)